# can I use log4net or Nlog to catch sql query error

Tags: c#, logging, mvp

My project is in MVP architecture . I wrote application_error() in global.asax.cs file but I cant get Server.GetLastError() cause breakpoint doesn't hit . So I am thinking to use log4net or Nlog to catch SQL Query errors . Can I use theses .NET frameworks to get query errors . If any way I can catch query error please suggest me . Please help

Comment: What kind of errors are you talking about? If you want to handle database errors on the code side you add proper exception handling to your code and of course, you can log the exception with whatever logging library you prefer to use

Comment: thank you @Steve for reply . I want to print my query or log query errors . how can I do that? do I need to use log4net for this?

Comment: You need to print/log where? File, console, any services?

Comment: in a text file .